# Discarding whitespace in a named pcre capture group

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to extract a small piece out of a log. I a regex that matches the whole log, but that only puts non whitespace content into one of my named capture groups.

The chunk of the log I'm looking at looks like this

```
</Data><Data Name='AccessMask'>0x100</Data><Data Name='Properties'>%%7688
        Default Property Set
            ms-MSS-XXXRRd
    computer
</Data><Data Name='AdditionalInfo'>-
```

Which I can match with this:

```
.*Default Property Set(?<tag32>.*?)<\/data>
```

However the output includes all of the whitespace and newlines around the extracted info.

```
    ms-MSS-XXXRRd
computer
```

Ideally the capture group should contain the following

```
ms-MSS-XXXRRd,computer
```

How do I keep the text in the named capture group, but discard the extra whitespace? I'm thinking some kind of nested capture groups, but that's getting beyond what I'm familiar with in regex.

Comment: `.*Default Property Set\s*(?<tag32>.*?)\s*<\/data>`

Comment: @ctwheels thanks, but I'm also trying to eliminate the whitespace between the lines as RRd and computer as well. Any ideas there?

Comment: This has to be done in 2 steps. Use the first regex to get the capture group into a string. Then, on that string, do a global find `\s+` and replace with a space.

Comment: Like x15 says. Only 1 step way is [to substitute the whole string to desired output](https://regex101.com/r/g6IUu9/1).